# DRF Serializers .orderitem_set.all()

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I was following serializer tutorial and came across some code that i did not understand its function.

```
def get_order_items(self, obj):
        items = obj.orderitem_set.all()
        print(obj)
        print(items)
        return OrderItemSerializer(items, many=True).data
```

What does the order item function do.
The snippet was from the serializer class below:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_items = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    """
    Calculate order_items field 
    """
    def get_order_items(self, obj):
        items = obj.orderitem_set.all()
        print(obj)
        print(items)
        return OrderItemSerializer(items, many=True).data

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('phone',
                  'first_name',
                  'delivery_date',
                  'delivery_time',
                  'address',
                  'comment',
                  'payment',
                  'order_items',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        items_data = validated_data.pop('order_items')
        order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for item_data in items_data:
            OrderItem.objects.create(order=order, **item_data)
        return order
```

Comment: You are getting all items which are related to orders object

Answer (score 0):

The order items functions serializes the `OrderItem` set, essentially converting in into a dictionary (or json) ready for you frontend to use because of the use of `.data`.

Grab objects -> Serialize -> Convert into json

So the result of that function will be a format that you can send as a response.

Answer (score 0):

This is a `MethodSerializer` that will obtain the `orderitem_set` of the given `Order` object `obj`. Then these items run through the `OrderItemSerializer` and the serializer data is collected and returned with the rest of the data of the `Order` if the user triggers the corresponding view.

Using a subserializer that way is however *not* recommended. You can use the subserializer directly as a field as is [explained in the documentation [Django-rest-doc]](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers):

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    order_items = serializers.OrderItemSerializer(source='orderitem_set', many=True)  # 🖘 use the OrderItemSerializer directly

    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('phone', 'first_name', 'delivery_date', 'delivery_time', 'address', 'comment', 'payment', 'order_items')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        items_data = validated_data.pop('order_items')
        order = Order.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for item_data in items_data:
            OrderItem.objects.create(order=order, **item_data)
        return order
```

Comment: Thanks for shedding light on the drf serializers.